# how to remove roles of guild member TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles') discord.js v14

Tags: node.js, discord.js

if the member got any role of the roleIDs the bot removes it

when i use guild.members.cache.get() it says

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')
```

when i use guild.members.fetch() it says [i removed .cache when i used fetch]

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some')
```

the code:

```
 var roleIDs = ["1048196394688725053","1051123574955589632"]
 const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
 const member = guild.members.cache.get(discordid)
          if(!result[0]){
          }else{
            
            if(JSON.stringify(e) =='-1'){
              
              if (member.roles.cache.some(role => roleIDs.includes(role.id))) {
                  await member.roles.remove(role => roleIDs.includes(role.id))
              }
              //member.setNickname(`[${result.id}]-${JSON.stringify(charname).replaceAll("_"," ")}`)
            }
           }
```

if the member got any role of the roleIDs the bot removes it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"TypeError [InvalidType]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes."
This is because you are attempting to remove a role with a filter function. This is not built in to the `\<GuildMemberRoleManager>#remove` method. Consider the following changes to remove all of the roles which also exist in the collection.

```js
await member.roles.remove(member.roles.cache.filter(r => roleIDs.includes(r.id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider fetching the GuildMember

```
const member = await guild.members.fetch(discordid);
```

Comment: TypeError [InvalidType]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74778251/how-to-remove-roles-of-guild-member-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefin/74779722#74779722